# Alternate Row Coloring in Django Template with More Than One Set of Rows

Tags: django, django-templates

Django templates offer the builtin tag `cycle` for alternating between several values at different points in a template (or for loop in a template) but this tag does not reset when it is accessed in a scope outside of the `cycle`s definition.  I.e., if you have two or more lists in your template, the rows of all of which you'd like to use some css definitions `odd` and `even`, the first row of a list will pick up where the last left off, not with a fresh iteration from the choices (`odd` and `even`)

E.g., in the following code, if the first blog has an odd number of entries, then the first entry in a second blog will start as `even`, when I want it to start at `odd`.

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
  {% for entry in blog.entries %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}" id="{{entry.id}}">
      {{entry.text}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried obviating this by patching with the `resetcycle` tag offered here:

[Django ticket: Cycle tag should reset after it steps out of scope](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5908)

to no avail.  (The code didn't work for me.)

I've also tried moving my inner loop into a custom tag, but this also did not work, perhaps because the compile/render cycle moves the loop back into the outer loop?  (Regardless of why, it didn't work for me.)

How can I accomplish this simple task!?  I'd prefer not to create a data structure in my view with this information pre-compiled; that seems unnecessary.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The easiest workaround (until the resetcycle patch gets fixed up and applied) is to use the built-in "divisibleby" filter with forloop.counter:

```
{% for entry in blog.entries %}
  <div class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}even{% else %}odd{% endif %}" id="{{ entry.id }}">
    {{ entry.text }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

A little more verbose, but not hard to understand and it works great.

Comment: One can also write that a little shorter (at least in Django 1.3): `{{forloop.counter|divisibleby:2|yesno:"even,odd"}}`

Comment: Nice enhancement, Michael! I've never really used the yesno filter much, but I think I've got a lot of if/elses in my templates that could be shortened that way.

Comment: See the answer below: `{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}`
That one is a way better solution, easier to read as well.
(This one with the forloop is reinventing the wheel with no reason)

Answer (score 24):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

```
{% for o in some_list %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it uses django to answer the question

Answer (score 3):

Give up and use [Jinja2 Template System](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/)

I gave up on django template language, it's very restricted in what you can do with it.
Jinja2 uses the same syntax that the django template uses, but adds many enhancements over it.

**EDIT/NOTE** ( I know it sounds like a big switch for just a minor issue, but in reality I bet you always find yourself fighting the default template system in django, so it really is worthwhile and I believe it will make you more productive in the long run. )

You can read [this article written by its author](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2008/9/16/why-jinja-is-not-django-and-why-django-should-have-a-look-at-it), although it's technical, he mentions the problem of the {% cycle %} tag in django.

Jinja doesn't have a cycle tag, it has a cycle method on the loop:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li class="{{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}">{{ user }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

A major advantage of Jinja2 is that it allows you to use logic for the presentation, so if you have a list of pictures, you can put them in a table, because you can start a new row inside a table every N elements, see, you can do for example:

```
{% if loop.index is divisibleby(5) %}   
     </tr>
     {% if not loop.last %}
     <tr>
     {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

you can also use mathematical expressions:

```
{% if x > 10 %}
```

and you can access your python functions directly (but some setup is required to specify which functions should be exposed for the template)

```
{% for item in normal_python_function_that_returns_a_query_or_a_list() %}
```

even set variables ..

```
{% set variable_name = function_that_returns_an_object_or_something() %}
```

Comment: That's a big switch to make (with some major complications, like third-party or contrib apps) for such a minor issue. -1

Comment: Good point to bring up. The thing is, I bet that people always find themselves fighting the django template system, it's not just this minor issue or that one, it's a whole pile of annoyances.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and article; I have felt limited by Django's approach to templating and annoyed by its bugs.  But Django's sweet overall.

Comment: I know, actually I love Django. It's not like I'm saying to throw django, just plug Jinja2 into its environment. :)

Comment: I have been very happy using Jinja2 templating, but I wanted to note that the Django templating language has improved significantly and I am now happily using it in new projects.  Now if only Django would implement an in-browser debugger...

Answer (score 3):

You can use tagged `cycle` and `resetcycle` (new in Django 1.11) calls (from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-resetcycle ):

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
  {% cycle 'odd' 'even' as rowcolors silent %}
  {% resetcycle rowcolors %}
  {% for entry in blog.entries %}
    {% cycle rowcolors %}
    <div class="{{ rowcolors }}" id="{{entry.id}}">
      {{ entry.text }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I end up doing so, with the forloop.counter0 - It works great!

```
{% for product in products %}

    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}<div class="clear"></div>{% endif %}

    <div class="product {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}col{% else %}col20{% endif    %}">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer might be: "give up and use jQuery."  If that's acceptable it's probably easier than fighting with Django's templates over something so simple.

Comment: This is what I do, though since I was using jQuery anyway, it was pretty trivial.

Answer (score -5):

There's a way to do it server-side with an iterator that doesn't keep a simultaneous copy of all the entries:

```
import itertools
return render_to_response('template.html',
  {
    "flattened_entries": itertools.chain(*(blog.entries for blog in blogs)),
  })
```

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem?  Seems like this is just another way to provide the wrong behavior (alternating row colors that don't reset between blog posts).  -1