# how to number t-rows ,when table generated using nested forloop in django templates

Tags: html, django-templates

This part is from views.py

```
results=[(A,[stuObj1,stuObj2,stuObj3]),(B,[stuObj4,stuObj5,stuObj6]),(C,[stuObj7,stuObj8])]
for tup in results:
    total = tot+len(tup[1])
render_to_response(url,{'results':res , 'total':str(tot),})
```

this is template code:

```
<th class="name">Name</th>
<th class="id">Student ID</th>
<th class="grade">Grade</th>
    {% for tup in results %}    
       {% for student in tup|last %}
           {% with forloop.parentloop.counter as parentloopid %}
           {% with forloop.counter as childloopid %}
        <tbody class="results-body">
        <tr>
            <td>{{student.fname|lower|capfirst}} {{student.lname|lower|capfirst}}</td>
            <td>{{student.id}}</td>
            <td>{{tup|first}}</td>
        </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
```

Now the problems am having are

1. numbering the rows. Here my problem is am not sure if i can do things like `total=total-1` in the templates to get the
   numbered rows like `<td>{{total}}</td>`
2. applying css to tr:even or odd.
   Whats happening in this case is everytime the loop is running the odd/even ordering is lost.

these seems related problems. Any ideas would be great :)

Comment: The row-numbering part is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13870890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer for my question:

1. Numbering would be a bit time taking. one option is to design custom filters or other way is to modify views and use simple `forloop.counter` to add, count and `forloop.counter`. Let me give an example: for the above cases, results are sorted dictionaries with grades and students,something like this `((A:a,b,c,d,e), (B:f,g,h,i), (C:j,k,l,m,n))`. In the view add one more dictionary to each tuple with the student count of previous tuple.

   ```
   temp_count = 0  
   for tup in results:  
       tup[1].append({'count':temp_count})  
       temp_count = temp_count + len(tup[1])-1
   ```

   `-1` is because we don't want to avoid dictionary counted
   Inside the template

   ```
   {% with tup|last|last as cnt %}  
       {% with forloop.counter as rnum %}  
           {% with rnum|add:cnt.count as rownum %}  
               <td>{{rownum}}</td>

               rest of code goes here 

           {% endwith %}
       {%endwith%}
   {% endwith %}
   ```
2. using `{% cycle %}` won't be that helpful when using nested loops,

   ```
   <tr class="{% if rownum|divisibleby:2 %}"even"{% else %}"odd"{% endif %}">
   ```

   follow this [clean way to color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459161/alternate-row-coloring-in-django-template-with-more-than-one-set-of-rows).

Answer (score 0):

For numbering the rows you can use the [forloop.counter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)
Here you can see an [example](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1391/) how to use it.

To switch between even and odd you can use the [cycle template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle)

```
{% for project in object_list %}

<tr class="{% cycle odd,even %}">  ... </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Tom forloop itself is good if i have had a single for loop. here as am using nested forloop.so the inner loops counter0 is always set to 0 when outerloop is increased. I'll tyr cycle and see .Thanks :)