# Can I evaluate expressions in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to display table rows with alternating colors. For that, I have two css classes row1 and row2 that I'd like to assign in an alternating pattern to the rows of a table. Ideally, I'd determine if the row is odd or even based on the forloop.counter variable

This is what I'd like the template to do (invalid code, but I think it's self explaning).

```
{% for norma in normas %}
{% if forloop.counter %2 != 0 %}
<tr class="row1">
{% else %}
<tr class="row2">
{% endif %}
    <td>yadda... yadda</td>
    .
    .
    .
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to do this within django template system?

Comment: here is solution to your problem
this post explains deeply how to get alternating row colors
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459161/alternate-row-coloring-in-django-template-with-more-than-one-set-of-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle) - the example shows this exact purpose

Comment: Thanks, this solves my particular problem. Is there a way to evaluate expressions though?

Answer (score 1):

Just use in your {%for%} loop :

```
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}>
```

django templete will cycle through each row. you can add as many items in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

the followin post explains how to get alternating row colors in Django.

[Alternate Row Coloring in Django Template with More Than One Set of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459161/alternate-row-coloring-in-django-template-with-more-than-one-set-of-rows)